# Cannot find closing comment tag to match: ko with: currentcustomers[0]

Tags: knockout.js

Why does this binding not work?

I get this exception:

Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko with: currentCustomers()[0]

```
 <!-- ko with: currentCustomers()[0] -->  

            <!-- ko foreach: orders -- />
                <div data-bind="text: title">ss
                </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

      <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: The `<!-- ko foreach: orders -- />` should be `<!-- ko foreach: orders -->`

Comment: Damn nemesv is fast : )

Comment: funny the first time I get a message from a computer system which is literally also my problem... :P Thanks nemesv for the eyes!

Comment: @nemesv, could you please put your comment as an answer so this question can be closed?  Thank you!